# How to remove first and last folder in 'find' result output?

Tags: bash

I want to search for folders by part of their name, which i know and it's common among these kind of folders. i used 'find' command in bash script like this

```
find . -type d -name "*.hg"
```

it just print out the whole path from current directory to the found folder itself. the foldr name has '.hg'.then i tried to use 'sed' command but i couldn't address the last part of the path. i decided to get the folder name ends in .hg save it in a variable then use 'sed' command to remove the last directory from output. i use this to get the last part, and try to save the result to a varable, no luck.

```
find . -type d -name "*.hg"|sed 's/*.hg$/ /'


find . -type d -name "*.hg"|awk -F/ '{print $NF}
```

this just print out the file names, here the folder with .hg at the end.
then i use different approach

```
for i in $(find . -type d -name '*.hg' ); 
do
    $DIR = $(dirname ${i})
    echo $DIR
done
```

this didin't work neither. can anyone point me any hint to make this works.
and yes it's homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
d=path/to/my/dir

d="${d#*/}" # remove the first dir
d="${d%/*}" # remove the last dir
echo $d     # "to/my"
```

Comment: I used your code and apply to my work like this $j               for i in $(find . -type d -name '*.hg' ); 
do
 $j="${i%/*}";
 echo $j;
done; it shows that output i wanted but with error: no such a file or directory.

Comment: i wanted to vote up @eugene answer but my reputation is low.anyway,i also used this code: find . -type d -name '*.hg' | xargs sed 's/*.hg$/ /g'. but showed me error.\.\..test.hg is a directory. indeed *.hg is a folder

Comment: i changed it to your suggestion, still no luck. let me explain more. i have a directory like this..Pamador/projects/c/test.hg. that test.hg is a folder wich contains other stuff. my problem is to run this script from my working directory then just prints out './projects/c/' thanks for your answer

Comment: worked...the problem was in missing bloody '*' . thank you for your responses. i learned a lot. one day i collect reputation and come here to vote you up...cheers

Answer (score 0):

one problem that you have is with the pattern you are using in your sed script - there is a different pattern language used by both bash and the find command.

They use a very simple regular expression language where * means any number of any character and ? means any single character. The sed command uses a much richer regular expression language where * means any number of the previous character and . means any character (there's a lot more to it than that).

So to remove the last component of the path delivered by find you will need to use the following sed command: sed -e 's,/[^/].hg,,'

Alternatively you could use the dirname command. Pipe the output of the find command to xargs (which will run a command passing standard input as arguments to the command:

xargs -i dirname

@Pamador - that's strange. It works for me. Just to explain: the sed command needs to be quoted in single quotes just to protect against any unwanted shell expansions. The character following the 's' is a comma; what we're doing here is changing the character that sed uses to separate the two parts of the substitute command, this means that we can use the slash character without having to escape it without a preceding backslash. The next part matches any sequence of characters apart from a slash followed by any character and then hg. Honestly I should have anchored the pattern to the end of line with a $ but apart from that it's fine.

I tested it with

```
echo "./abc/xxx.hg" | sed -e 's,/[^/]\.hg$'
```

And it printed ./abc

Did I misunderstand what you wanted to do?

Comment: thanks you for your response, i tried the 'sed' you provided but it didin't work. is the chracter after 's' is , or . i tried every possibilities . , / but it didn't give the result i wanted.

Comment: I tried exactly this and gave me error.sed -e expression #1, char 12 unterminated 's' command. i know the forslash is delimiter, first is the text to find and second is the text to replace. i don't understand the what the (,) here is doing?

Comment: Sorry there were a couple of missing commas just before the final quote. The first character after the s is the command delimiter. It is typically a / but using a comma avoids the "leaning toothpick" problem where you have to escape slashes in the pattern with backslashes

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type d -name "*.hg" | awk -v m=1 -v n=1 'NR<=m{};NR>n+m{print line[NR%n]};{line[NR%n]=$0}'
```

awk parameters:

- m = number of lines to remove from beginning of output
- n = number of
  lines to remove from end of output

Bonus: If you wanted to remove 1 line from the end and you have coreutils installed, you could do this:  `find . -type d -name "*.hg" | ghead -n -1`